# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'verify_password'

Tags: heroku, flask, flask-httpauth

I am trying to incorporate basic authentication as shown in this link

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-HTTPAuth/blob/master/examples/basic_auth.py

in my flask app. The app is deployed on Heroku. The error I keep getting is

```
@auth.verify_password 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'verify_password'
```

Below is my code

```
import urllib
import json
import os
import string
import random

from flask import Flask,render_template,request
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, asc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, User
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask import request
from flask import make_response
from flask import session as login_session
from flask import make_response
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username_or_token, password):
    #Try to see if it's a token first
    user_id = User.verify_auth_token(username_or_token)
    if user_id:
        user = session.query(User).filter_by(id = user_id).one()
    else:
        user = session.query(User).filter_by(username = username_or_token).first()
        if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
            return False
    g.user = user
    return True
```

Below is the traceback

```
2017-02-14T19:28:58.375416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-02-14T19:29:01.124995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python test.py`
2017-02-14T19:29:04.255161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-02-14T19:29:04.127534+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-02-14T19:29:04.127556+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "test.py", line 234, in <module>
2017-02-14T19:29:04.127594+00:00 app[web.1]:     @auth.verify_password
2017-02-14T19:29:04.127622+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'verify_password'
2017-02-14T19:29:04.299349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-02-14T19:29:04.300161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

My requirements.txt file contains the following

```
click==6.7
Flask==0.12
httplib2==0.9.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.4
MarkupSafe==0.23
passlib==1.7.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.5
virtualenv==15.1.0
Werkzeug==0.11.15
Flask-HTTPauth==3.2.2
```

Can someone help me figure out what the issue is? I have all the correct imports as suggested on the GitHub example and also have them correctly mentioned in my requirements.txt file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you declare `auth = HTTPBasicAuth()`?  That's done in the link you provided, but you don't show that here in your code.

Comment: Yes I did. This was just a snippet. It got resolved However. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The same question was posted on the GitHub repository, and was resolved there. Link: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-HTTPAuth/issues/53